# Android Webview - how to navigate to the NEXT occurence of the searched text

Tags: android, android-webview

Searching for a text in a WebView is easy. Navigating to the first occurence of the searched text goes like this:

```
 webView.findAllAsync(whatToFind);
    webView.setFindListener((i, i1, b) -> {
        if (b) {
            webView.findNext(true);
        }
    });
```

How can I navigate to the **NEXT** occurence of the searched text?

I tried this but this will not navigate to the next occurence.

```
webView.findNext(true);
```

I loaded the webview in this way:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", formatHtmlContent(content), "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

**SOLUTION**: Thanks to Du.Fantasy:
Don't use the 'setFindListener' - unless you really need it. Take care of the timing when you use the findAllAsync.

Comment: Did you check if your `b` is `true`?

Comment: The first navigation was ok. So, 'b' must be true, otherwise the navigation to the first search text was not done. Should I do again, having an else ?

Comment: Do you have a button that is supposed to trigger next `WebView` result? From its `OnClickListener`, you could invoke `webView.findNext(true);`

Comment: Yes, a button triggering findNext(true).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's enough to just call  `webView.findNext(true);` But you need to be sure that calling `webView.findAllAsync("string");` before when page is fully loaded. e.g. call it in `onPageFinished` or even delay a few seconds. I tested on Pixel 3 and it's working fine.  I have recorded a video but I don't know how to post it here.

eidt: please see the gif below:

https://ftp.bmp.ovh/imgs/2021/04/166643b9c504af01.gif

Comment: Tx. Will try this in the evening. The gif shows a 404 http code: image not found.

Comment: @tm1701 Please try the new link: https://ftp.bmp.ovh/imgs/2021/04/166643b9c504af01.gif

Comment: Looks good! Nice demo (via the GIF). Will try that this evening.

Comment: The problem was the findListener. Don't use it - unless you really need to.